Creating a surface with ASE (Atomic simulation Environment)
I want to create the (4×2) Rutile TiO2(110) surface and the surface slab consisting of five TiO2 trilayers (or 15 atomic layers)
I did that, but I don't if it is correct or not!
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.build import surface, make_supercell
from ase.build.tools import cut
from ase.visualize import view
structA=read('TiO2.cif', format='cif')
structB=surface(structA, (1,1,0), 5, 0)
write('110.cif', structB, format='cif')
#Make (4x2) (110) surface.
M = [[4, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
cif = read('110.cif')
sc=make_supercell(cif, M)
write('super.cif', sc, format='cif')
vac = read('super.cif')
vac.center(vacuum=10, axis=2)
write('super_vacumm.cif', vac, format='cif')


+1. Welcome to our community.

I would suggest using a visualisation tool like VESTA or Jmol (other brands are available) would be good; at least you can see if the results look sane by eye.
